# Update the value of a model dynamically, by performing operations

Tags: python, django

I have 2 models, Order and Expense. The Expenses are based on Order ID. Whenever I add an expense, this should add to the total expense of the respective order.

**Models.py**

```
class Order(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="order",blank=True,null=True)
    client_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    event_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    event_description = models.TextField(max_length=300,null=True,blank=True)
    expenses = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0,null=True,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.client_name

class ProjectExpense(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="project_expense",null=True,blank=True)
    order_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(default='0',null=True,blank=True)
    exp = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    exp_desc = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
    amount = models.PositiveIntegerField(default='0')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.exp
```

Comment: Relational model normalization 101: do not store values that can be computed from other values. This _will_ end up in wrong data at some point. Use your db's aggregation functions (`sum` in this case) to get the result.

Comment: Is it not order_id ForeignKey?